# C#: Text file with 4 letter words, separated with tabs - how do I convert them to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, text

I have four_letter.txt text file with all 4-letter English words, separated with tabs. 
How can I convert this text file into an array in C#, so that each element of the array is one 4-letter word?

Thanks for he answer in advance!

PS.: I have been looking through Google a couple of times, but I was probably looking for the wrong keywords. Also note, that I am a complete beginner in C#...

Comment: you better write couple of lines of that file as a sample, and a sample output. Also maybe it is good to mention what is the difficulty you are facing, is it reading the file content, or processing it, like you don't know how to split  the text on tabs.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question we expect you to show your research and attempts in solving the problem. As this question can be answered by a quick and simple Google search, most people will likely assume that you didn't do any research at all. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for information on how this site works.

Comment: I actually can't understand that you didn't find anything at all because simply googling [C# string separated with tabs convert to array](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+string+separated+with+tabs+convert+to+array) (or even simpler [C# string with tabs to array](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+string+with+tabs+to+array)) gives you lots of examples and documentation of how you can do it.

Comment: Maybe that I didn't even know what exactly to look for..? But I see your point, and as I have the answer now (and it works), I won't face this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllText("four_letter.txt").Split('\t');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new List<string>();

using (var sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        array.AddRange(line.Split('\t'));
    }
}
```